# How to get total html5 storage size used by current application

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I need a way to find the total size taken by an application using HTML5 `sessionStorage`/ `localStorage` at run time.

I don't want profiler-based approaches.

What I'm currently doing is -

```
var data = 0;
for(var v in window.sessionStorage){
 data += window.sessionStorage.getItem(v); 
}

console.log(data);//.length to get char length
```

And then I copy-paste this value into a text-file and check the size.

Ugly and still doesn't help me either. Is there a way (any method) in the HTML5 API's that have this in-built?

Thank you.

Comment: since this is stringified `data.length` should at least give you the number of characters.

Comment: @Christoph: Yes, as I have already mentioned in my question. Are you suggesting multiplying it by some assumed byte weightage per character?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**No, not cross browser**. IE sort of [has it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197016%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), the others don't. But of course, remaining size left *on the domain* can be calculated. See below examples.

For IE only:

```
var remSpace = window.localStorage.remainingSpace;
```

For FF/Chrome/Safari:

```
 var limit = 1024 * 1024 * 5; // 5 MB
 var remSpace = limit - unescape(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(localStorage))).length;
```

Opera:
5 MB is standard but the browser offers to increase limit as applications require more space.

Comment: Neat :) I can live with that since I don't expect it to exceed 5 MB.

Comment: problem here is that total memory is assumed to be 5mb, but you can tweak for instance, ff to increase that.

Comment: But the limit looks to be 10 MB in chromium. Refer: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/common/dom_storage/dom_storage_types.h?dr=C&l=24

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while trying to find my own solution to this problem and wanted to share where I ended up, just in case it may prove helpful for others.

The short of it, is that when I add a value to localStorage, I put its key in an array. Then, before writing something else to localStorage, I loop through the keys and get a sum of their lengths to be sure I'm not over a threshold that I'm comfortable with.

If localStorage is larger than 2Mb (in this case), then it removes the first item from localStorage, removes that entry from the array, and then writes the new entry.

```
// check the size of localStorage

var localStorageArray = [];
var localStorageSize = 0;

for ( var i=0; i < localStorageArray.length; i++ ) {
    localStorageSize += localStorage.getItem(localStorageArray[i]).length;
}

// save to localStorage if it has not been saved already

if ( !localStorage.getItem(key) ){
    if ( localStorageSize < 2000000 ) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
        localStorageArray.push(key);
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem(localStorageArray[0]);
        localStorageArray.shift();
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
        localStorageArray.push(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. But isn't this checking if there are 2 million `value` characters? What about sizes of the `keys`? Also shouldn't I be checking against `1024 * 1024 * 2` (for 2 MB)?